# Universe made of rock

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Years ago - the 1980s - I read a short story in which a universe is made of rock or stone, within which are voids, some inhabited by intelligent races. I've always thought it was in *The Monadic Universe* by George Zebrowski, but I now have a copy of that book, and it isn't one of the stories. Any ideas?

Comment: Incidentally, the universe of Fritz Leiber's Fafhrd & The Gray Mouser stories is at one point shown to be like this.

Comment: From the title I was hoping for a universe made of rock the music.

Comment: @Klaus Æ. Mogensen - According to Wikipedia, "Theorists in Nehwon believe that their world may be shaped like a bubble, floating in the waters of eternity."   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fafhrd_and_the_Gray_Mouser

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Could it be [Me and My Antronoscope](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1056202) (1973) by [Barrington Bayley](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?94717) in his collection [The Knights of the Limits](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?120071) (1980) ?

From the text:

> It had been recognised for a long time that the universe was
> stratified. **In any transverse direction the rock remained, as far as
> was known, unchanged to infinity.** Downwards, one entered a Region of
> Intense Heat, while if one attempted to travel Upwards one encountered
> a Region of Impassibility. Above this region, which could be entered
> only by the souls of the righteous after death, God was acknowledged
> to dwell. Conversely the profound Region of Heat was a place of
> torment reserved for the souls of the wicked. Both regions were held
> to be infinite in themselves, but to Erled, or indeed to anyone else
> in the room, the very idea of travel either Up or Down for more than a
> few hundred miles was virtually a metaphysical notion. These
> transcendental directions were literally beyond possible human
> experience. Only horizontal directions had any practical meaning, and
> it was these that one normally meant by infinity.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this might be the right answer?

Comment: @Valorum - I recognise the story title. I remember enough of the story to be sure this answer is correct, and I have Googled the title + author and recognised an image of the cover of the paperback edition I had. Dosco, many thanks!

Comment: The question reminded me of a story I once read which I'm reasonably sure wasn't this one either. The word "Voids" being a key part of the description for me.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the year doesn't match (and it's not a short story but a series), but in case someone else comes here looking:

A universe of rock with voids in them sounds like [the Death Gate cycle](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41764-the-death-gate-cycle) (1990 - 1994) by Margaret Weis and Tracy Hickman. The series takes place on several connected worlds, one of which is a world of solid rock where people live in cave systems.